# Error: VS30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: redhat, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

We are trying to install and configure the agent on [RedHat](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-linux#permissions). 
1. I can able to unzip and install agent on Red Hat
2. While running ./Config.sh, I choose negotiate authentication and provided username in the format of Domain\user then password
3. Now am getting error, Error: VS30063: You are not authorized to access

FYI, we are using TFS 2015.3 version, I have administrator access on server level and also I can connect to TFS by using same loginsthrough IE/chrome.

Could please help me to resolve the above error

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the result if you try it with another account or in another machine?

Comment: is that account have Agent Pool Administrator Permission?

Comment: yes, I have added my credentials to Agent pool administrators of Default Agent pool. Still am getting same error as described above. please advise me further

Comment: after entering./config.sh, am specifying only TFS url "http://*****:8080/tfs". Do I need to mention any other details?

Comment: @Sam What's the result if you try it with another account or in another machine?

Comment: What's the authentication type you enabled on TFS server?

Answer (score 0):

Add user here to get Agent Pool Administrator Permission

[image]

Comment: I cant able to see attached image in the comment. FYI,  
yes, I have added my credentials to Agent pool administrators of Default Agent pool, still am getting same error